# ##[error]EXEC(0,0): Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2146893779/0x8009002d)

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, yaml, signtool

While using the Signtool on our build server (windows server 2019) azure-devops pipeline has below error, its a DotNetCoreCLI@2 task:

```
    ##[error]EXEC(0,0): Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2146893779/0x8009002d)
EXEC : error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2146893779/0x8009002d) 
##[error]EXEC(0,0): Error : An unexpected internal error has occurred.
EXEC : SignTool error : An unexpected internal error has occurred. 
Error MSB3073: The command "if Release == Release ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\Signtool.exe" sign /sha1 abcd1234 /v /fd sha256 /td sha256 /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com "abcd.dll")" exited with code 1.
```

I have tried to update the signtool to latest and still its the exact same error as pipeline. Running manually on the server gives same error. The arguments for the task is:

```
arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration) -p:PX_CERT_SNK_PATH=/cert/cert.snk /p:VersionNumber=$(applicationVersion) /p:Platform=x86 /p:CodeSigningCertificateFingerprint=$(codeSigningCertificateFingerprint)'
```

Comment: Hi, do you mean that if you manually use Signtool, the same error will occur without using the azure-devops pipeline? By the way, I checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/how-to-sign-a-package-using-signtool#troubleshooting-app-package-signing-errors) and found the error code  means `NTE_INTERNAL_ERROR 0x8009002D An internal consistency check failed.`

Comment: The key is stored in Azure KeyVault?

Comment: Thank you.
The issue is fixed. For the latest certificates from the Digicert they have this need where the signing cannot happen on the individual project file level it has to be in the pipeline which is building the code. So after moving the signing code bit it worked.

Comment: We had the same issue/error reported 0x8009002d when using Digicerts with signtool, which turned out to be access denied by Digicert in our case - if you check the digicert logs (smksp.log). When using the Digicert certs it uses the Digicert CSP which attempts to validate the user back to digicert with 2FA, if that fails you get that error. So once that is correctly configured you can sign using msbuild in the csproj file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you. The issue is fixed. For the latest certificates from the Digicert one they have this need where the signing cannot happen on the individual project file level it has to be in the pipeline which is building the code. So after moving the signing code bit out of our .csproj file it worked.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by "moving" the signing code? What did you move it into?

Comment: BTW, these errors went away for us after 30 minutes or so. As far as we can tell it was a temporary issue with DigiCert's servers.

Comment: @DylanNicholson it was there for couple of days many attempts to fix it before i posted it here. 
I removed the 'sign' command from the .csproj file and moved the command to .yml files (azure pipeline)

Comment: We tried that, made no difference at the time, nor could I really see how it could, unless there was something changing the relevant environment variables.

Comment: I have been getting this exact same error all day today. Makes me think this is a server-side issue, and it has returned.